# Не могу разобраться в промисах JS

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

Я давно пытаюсь разобраться в промисах. Я уже много читал, но что то понять до конца как и что - не могу. Вот и сейчас мне надо написать некую функцию

```
export const setSetting = async (key, value) => {
    return await RNFS.readFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/setting.dat', 'utf8')
        .then(async result => {
            let setting = JSON.parse(result)
            setting[key] = value;
            await RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/setting.dat', JSON.stringify(setting), 'utf8')
                .then((success) => {
                    return true
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return false
                });
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return false
        })
}
```

В коде вызываю ее

```
const result = setSetting('lang', 'ru')
console.log('[Log]', result)
```

И в консоли получаю

```
[Log] {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
```

Помогите разобраться что я делаю не так или может подскажите хорошую статью или видео

Comment: Подробностей не помню, но была такая же проблема. Заключается в том, что вы дождались не того результата, попробуйте добавить еще один then сразу за первым, вроде должно получиться то что нужно.

Comment: Механизм async/await это синтаксический сахар над промисами. Чтоб избежать путаницы, лучше использовать что-то одно. Лучше просто жить с async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как работают `Promise`? Промис - это один из способов борьбы с так называемой [`callback-hell`](http://callbackhell.ru/).

Можно разобрать на простом примере с `setTimeout()`.

```js
btn.onclick = () =>
  // Как провило callback промиса имеет два аргумента
  // При выполнении оба аргумента содержат функции
  // Первую функцию мы вызовем, когда промис отработал
  // Вторую вызываем если всё пошло не как по маслу и закончилось с ошибкой
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    // Тут вместо setTimeout долго-выполняющаяся функция
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Пусть наша функция работает нестабильно
      // и с вероятностью 50% завершится ошибкой
      if (Math.random() > .5) {
        let result = 'success';
        // Возвращаем результат работы промиса
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        let error = new Error();
        // Возвращаем причину невыполненного промиса
        reject(error);
      }
    }, 500)
  )
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.error(error.stack));
```

```html
<button id="btn"> Нажми меня несколько раз </button>
```

Что такое `async`-`await`?

```js
btn.onclick = async() => {
  // Так как наш код нестабильный, мы используем конструкцию try-catch
  try {
    // await дожидается конца работы промиса и передаёт результат в result
    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      // Внутри промиса всё осталось как в прошлом примере
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
          let result = 'success';
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          let error = new Error();
          reject(error);
        }
      }, 500)
    );
    // Вывод результата
    console.log(result);
  }
  // Но когда что-то прошло не как по маслу 
  catch (error) {
    // Вывод ошибки
    console.error(error.stack);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"> Нажми меня несколько раз </button>
```

Благодаря await мы можем использовать асинхронные функции в циклах:

```js
// Функция из прошлых примеров немного упрощена.
function wait(ms) {
  // Наш промис просто ждёт пока setTimeout отсчитает ms микросекунд
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms));
}

// Здесь мы определяем функцию и сразу вызываем её
(async function test(){

  // Заполним массив числами по порядку
  let array = new Array(20).fill().keys();
  
  // Цикл перебирает эти числа
  for(let num of array){

    // await ожидает пока выполнится wait()
    let result = await wait( num * 100 );

    // Выводим прогресс выполнения
    console.log( result );
  }
  
  console.log('Работа выполнена');
  
})();
```

В следующем примере попробуйте самостоятельно разобраться, почему массив отсортировался?
По какому такому принципу? Как работает алгоритм?

```js
// Функция из предыдущего примера
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms));
}

async function magickSort(array){
  let sorted = [];

  await Promise.all( array
                 .map( number => wait(number)
                                   .then( result => sorted.push(result))
                 )
  );
  
  console.log('Отсортированный массив:', sorted.join(','));
}


// Наполним массив 20 рандомными числами
let array = new Array(20).fill().map(()=>~~(1000*Math.random()));
console.log('Исходный массив:', array.join(','));

magickSort(array);
```

Теперь разберем ваш пример.

Первая ошибка

```
const result = setSetting('lang', 'ru')
console.log('[Log]', result)
```

Надо так:

```
setSetting('lang', 'ru').then(result => console.log('[Log]', result));
```

или так:

```
(async()=>{ 
  const result = await setSetting('lang', 'ru');
  console.log('[Log]', result);
})()
```

Вторая ошибка заключается в том, что, если функция возвращает промис и больше ничего не делает, нет смысла делать её асинхронной и ставить await перед промисом, так как результатом асинхронной функции всё равно будет промис, и он также потребует ожидания. Но, раз уж вы сделали функцию асинхронной, тогда не стоит использовать `.then().catch()`. Это конечно не запрещается, но гораздо нагляднее будет вот так:

```
export const setSetting = async (key, value) => {
  try{
    let result = await RNFS.readFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/setting.dat', 'utf8');
    let setting = JSON.parse(result);
    setting[key] = value;
    let success = await RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/setting.dat', JSON.stringify(setting), 'utf8');
    return success;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```