# не получается присвоить переменной promiseresult

Tags: javascript, promise

загуглив нашел такое решение:
let posts = getPosts().then(resp => posts = resp)

но у меня все еще не присваивается promiseresult к переменной, а просто показывается обычный Promise[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хотелось бы получить результат как с:

```
let posts = getPosts().then(posts => console.log(posts))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для этого нужно писать перед  вызовом функции `await`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1363618/406363